# Question with R and repeated measures

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

Second time I'm turning to this site, it has helped before. I am looking for some coding help to perform a repeated measures anova in R. I have a total of 4 treatments, each replicated 3 times. They were monitored daily for several months, giving me a value of X each day. So the data is laid out like so:

```
Day     Trt     Rep     X
1       1       1       0
1       1       2       0
1       1       3       1
1       2       1       0
1       2       2       0
1       2       3       0
1       3       1       0
1       3       2       0
1       3       3       0
1       4       1       1
1       4       2       1
1       4       3       1
```

What is some example code that would allow me to perform a repeated measures ANOVA on this data?

Comment: ?aov for an example of type-I or ?anova for example of type-II & -III.

Comment: Is X really binomial?  If so you may want to see http://www.scopus.com/record/display.url?eid=2-s2.0-55649087772&origin=inward&txGid=XU_vtEnXdH4ZrDNyQ8FX2Q-%3a29

Comment: Sorry, I missed these comments earlier. X is not binomial, its a continuous variable ranging from 0 to 1, I just put that data in a a placeholder. I'm thinking it will be a Type I as I have no missing data (excuse me if I'm wrong, I'm not too well versed in stats.)

Comment: Good guide for your case for ANOVA repeated measures.
https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/repeated-measures-anova-statistical-guide.php

Comment: Which are your between- and within-subject variables?

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use my `afex` package ([on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/afex/index.html)) with function `ez.glm`.

Alternatively you could use `ezANOVA` from the `ez` package (also on CRAN).

Both functions are basically wrappers for `car::Anova()`. However, both need a variable coding the subject (i.e., a subject identifier). I don't know what it is in your case.
Otherwise, the call to `ez.glm` would be:

```
ez.glm(id, dv, data, between = NULL, within = NULL, covariate = NULL)
```

You need to specify `id`, `dv`, and `data`. You may specify which are your between and within-subject variables (assuming your data is in a data.frame called `dat`):

```
nice.anova(ez.glm(id = UNKONW, dv = "x", data = dat, between = "Trt", 
          within = c("Day", "Rep")))
```

Note, the call to `nice.anova`, produces a nice ANOVA table (using Greenhouse-Geisser correction of degrees-of-freedom).